# Connection from my output pin to avi mux

Tags: c++, directshow

I want my filter to be accepted as input to avi mux filter. But it rejects the connection with a  VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT error.

Here's what I did:

In my outputpin class i implemented the `Connect(IPin* pin, AM_MEDIA_TYPE *pmt)` method.
Then I call my `GetMediaType` function, which gives me `CMediaType` Object:

> See bellow for GetMEdiaTypeMethod

As you can see it has major type of `MEDIATYPE_Stream` as well as a subtype of `MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi` as this is the format the avi mux filter will accept.

Finally in `Connect` I call `ReceiveConnection` method of my peer pin.

Here's my whole Connect method:

```
 HRESULT MCMyOutputPin::Connect(IPin* pPin, const AM_MEDIA_TYPE *pmt)
{



    CMediaType* mediatype;
    HRESULT hr = GetMediaType(0, mediatype);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = pPin->ReceiveConnection(this, mediatype);
    return hr;
}
```

edit: I still haven't solved the problem. It still keeps rejecting the connection.
Here is my new GetMediaType Method that initializes AM_MEDIA_TYPE with all its needed values and structures:

```
HRESULT MCMyOutputPin::GetMediaType(int i, CMediaType *pmt)
{
    if (i < 0)
    {

        myLogger->LogDebug("Invalid arg in getmediatype", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    if (i == 0)
    {
        myLogger->LogDebug("On GetMediaType", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
        VIDEOINFO *pvi = (VIDEOINFO *)pmt->AllocFormatBuffer(sizeof(VIDEOINFO));
        if (NULL == pvi)
            return(E_OUTOFMEMORY);

        ZeroMemory(pvi, sizeof(VIDEOINFO));



        pvi->bmiHeader.biCompression = 0x3231564e;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 12;

        pvi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        pvi->bmiHeader.biWidth = 256;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biHeight = 240;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        pvi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = GetBitmapSize(&pvi->bmiHeader);
        pvi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;


        pvi->AvgTimePerFrame = 333333;
        pvi->dwBitRate = 0;
        pvi->dwBitErrorRate = 0;
        SetRectEmpty(&(pvi->rcSource));
        SetRectEmpty(&(pvi->rcTarget));
        pmt->SetFormatType(&FORMAT_VideoInfo);
        pmt->SetFormat((BYTE*)pvi, sizeof(pvi));
        pmt->SetTemporalCompression(FALSE);
        pmt->SetType(&MEDIATYPE_Video);
        const GUID SubTypeGUID = GetBitmapSubtype(&pvi->bmiHeader);
        pmt->SetSubtype(&SubTypeGUID);
        pmt->SetSampleSize(pvi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage);

        return S_OK;


    }
    return VFW_S_NO_MORE_ITEMS;
}
```

Here are the filters I want to connect:

[image]

Here is the graph construction report I get when i try to connect the filters:

```
0.000 sec Filter Selected : ffdshow Video Decoder 

0.015 sec Created filter  
 CLSID {04FE9017-F873-410E-871E-AB91661A4EF7} 
Object Name  
Merit 0xff800001 
Version 0x00000002 

0.015 sec Filter Selected : DirectVobSub (auto-loading version) 

0.046 sec Created filter  
 CLSID {9852A670-F845-491B-9BE6-EBD841B8A613} 
Object Name  
Merit 0x00800002 
Version 0x00000002 


0.046 sec Filter Selected : WMVideo8 Encoder DMO 

0.046 sec  
 CLSID {94297043-BD82-4DFD-B0DE-8177739C6D20} 

0.046 sec Filter Selected : WMVideo9 Encoder DMO 

0.046 sec  
 CLSID {94297043-BD82-4DFD-B0DE-8177739C6D20} 

0.046 sec Filter Selected : AVI Decompressor 

0.046 sec Created filter  
 CLSID {CF49D4E0-1115-11CE-B03A-0020AF0BA770} 
Object Name  
Merit 0x00600000 
Version 0x00000002
```

I updated my GetMediaType method according to a sample in the sdk. But it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Your output pin says it provides Stream of AVI type but this is *not* what AVI Mux wants, this is what it should produce itself. What it wants for input is a video stream or an audio stream or maybe some other type of data but not an AVI stream. What kind of data your filter really produces? If it's some video, then output major type = Video, subtype = guid of your video format.

Comment: my filter produces video data with NV12 format. But passing this still gives the same error. Do I have to set pbFormat in Connect method?

Comment: and initialize a VIDEOINFOHEADER2 structure?

Comment: Yes, your filter produces some data and should describe the data format in all details. But not in Connect method. Your output pin should describe its media format in IPin::EnumMediaTypes.

Comment: do i have to call EnumMediaTypes in Connect and call ReceiveConnection with each media_type until it is accepted?

Comment: Not really. You already know media type of data your filter produces, what are you going to enumerate? But to let other filters and graph builder know your data type you should implement EnumMediaTypes. Please read in MSDN about connection process. And look at BaseClasses in SDK samples, especially CTransformFilter. They are very helpful.